# Wordpress backend text only

Tags: wordpress

When I log into my Wordpress backend it is text only.  This is on my test website, where I trial and make changes prior to making changes on the live site.

I have tried the following:
1. Disabled all plugins.
2. Removed .htaccess.
3. Restored to a known working point.
4. Tried copying the live site that works, then updated wpconfig.php and the database.

Despite the above, it is the same result - Wordpress backend is text only.

Help please to get my website working normally again.

Thanks

Comment: Have also turned on: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); But nothing obvious in the debug log.

Comment: What do you mean "text only"? As in no stylesheets being loaded or something like that?

Comment: Yes as in its not the normal graphical interface - just page of links and text.  When you click on the links they typically don't work